# How to create a navigation out of hexagonal shapes

Tags: html, css, background, navigation

I've created this hexagonal navigation to fit within a website.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/14577801@N00/11202239254/

I'm wanting to know what would be the best way to go about creating the structure of the navigation in html and css. Where the links are within the white hexagons, I would like hovering over these links to change the white background to a colour. I've tried to do this with using background images, but haven't quite got there. The surrounding coloured hexagons I've been using as a whole background image for the navigation.

I found this on the web: http://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html , which I think could be great to use, but I thought there must be a way to use background images.

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: http://blog.readingroom.com/2013/08/07/css-hexagons-and-a-hybrid-solution/

Answer (score 0):

The color of an element (in this case, a hexagon) can be changed on hover with css. If we add this to the style properties in your css-hexagon tutorial:

```
.hex:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
.hex:hover:before {
    border-bottom: 30px solid blue;
}
.hex:hover:after {
    border-top: 30px solid blue;
}
```

The hexagon will change color when the cursor hovers over it, which you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v52PG/).

You can find good documentation of the CSS :hover pseudo-class here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover